# .NET heic to jpeg with magick

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a project that can store image on azure blob storage. But there is a problem. I want to convert heic to jpeg and downloaded magick NuGet package. This is my code and not working.

```
BlobClient client = container.GetBlobClient(blob.FileName);

await using (Stream? data = blob.OpenReadStream())
{
  if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(blob.FileName) == ".heic")
  {
    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(data))
    {
      image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
      byte[] b = image.ToByteArray();
      using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(b))
      {
        await client.UploadAsync(s);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not sufficient debugging information to go on. Please [edit] your question to include the text of any errors that might have been thrown. You may want to review [ask] for more tips.

Comment: there is no error. it's just not working. i mean  the data at blob storage still with .heic extensiom.

Comment: Why would it have anything other than the same name? You don't change `blob.FileName`...

Comment: are you really want help? there is no magic on naming files based on the content. if you expect a file with a special name then you have to name it, period.

Comment: you are responsible for naming the files, IM sure threres a flag on the upload which u can set to simply override the file if it exists then u wont get the exception. Please update the titile this has noting to do with "heic to jpeg with magick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a test in my side and I'm afraid the issue is related with the blob name.

Here's my code snippet.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> uploadToBlobAsync() {
    var connectionString = "connection_string";
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("tinycontainer");
    await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    List<BlobItem> files = new List<BlobItem>();
    await foreach (BlobItem item in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
    {
        var name = item.Name;
        files.Add(item);
    }
    var itemInBlob = files[0];
    BlobClient client = containerClient.GetBlobClient(itemInBlob.Name);
    var data = await client.OpenReadAsync();
    Stream blobContent = data;

    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("myjpg.jpeg");

    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(blobContent))
    {
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
        byte[] dd = image.ToByteArray();
        using (MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream(dd))
        {
            //await client.UploadAsync(mm);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(mm);
        }
    }
    return "success";
}
```

When I used `await client.UploadAsync(mm)`, I got the exception indicating that the file is already existing. If I changed to use `await blobClient.UploadAsync(mm)`, then I can got a newly uploaded file `myjpg.jpeg`.

[image]

test result.

[image]